# date from string to datetime.date in python

Tags: python, date, datetime

Can this be done any way more pythonic?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date = '20131018'
>>> date
'20131018'
>>> year, month, day = date[0:4], date[4:6], date[6:]
>>> datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
datetime.date(2013, 10, 18)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Python already has a built-in way of parsing dates from strings in the datetime package, namely [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> date = '20131018'
>>> dt.strptime(date, "%Y%m%d").date()
datetime.date(2013, 10, 18)
```

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for all of the available format / parsing options.

Comment: `strptime` returns a `datetime`, not a `date` as your example shows.  You need to call `date()` on the newly created datetime: `dt.strptime(date, "%Y%m%d").date()`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - valid point - I've updated my answer. Thanks!